# Function similar to Heaviside function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, partial-differential-equations

I was looking for a function, $f(x) = 1$ if $x = a$, and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. otherwise. I was thinking of letting f(x) = H(x-a), where H is the Heaviside function, but this doesn't quite work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this

$$
f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\eta_{\epsilon}
$$

where $\eta_\epsilon$ is any of the following functions

\begin{eqnarray*}
\eta_\epsilon &=& \frac{1}{\pi x}\sin\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon} \right)\\
\eta_\epsilon &=& \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi \epsilon}}e^{-x^2/4\epsilon} \\
\eta_\epsilon &=& \frac{1}{2}\epsilon |x|^{\epsilon - 1} \\
&...&
\end{eqnarray*}

I guess it depends on the problem you're trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the Heaviside function to do this;

$$2*H(-|x-a|) = 1 \quad if \quad x=a$$
$$2*H(-|x-a|) = 0 \quad if \quad x\neq a$$

Extra:

There may be room to alternatively use the [kronecker delta](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerDelta.html) which is simply defined as
$$\delta_{ij} = 0 \quad if \quad i\neq j$$ and
$$\delta_{ij} = 1 \quad if \quad i=j.$$

For a continuous version you could possibly use the [(Dirac) delta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html)